# Could there be a dark matter planet?

Tags: planets, dark-matter

Since dark matter is gravitationally "charged", by which I mean it has mass and attracts things, could it bunch together to form a planet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we have a parallel earth made of dark matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61223/)

Comment: While the question isn't quite the same, the answer by Chris White discusses why a planet couldn't be comprised of dark matter.

Comment: The minimum halo mass of dark matter is model dependent with some dark matter models allowing earth mass halos and other requiring the minimum halo size to be much larger.

Comment: It is not that simple, look at this model for the formation of the solar system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebular_hypothesis . Dark matter with its unknown particles would be an extra complication in the story.