# Dark Civilizations?

Tags: universe, dark-matter

I just read that maybe the dark matter could have dark forces.

Hence, I wonder: dark atoms, dark galaxies, dark intelligent beings. Basically a parallel, interpenetrating universe. Is this plausible?

Comment: No, I'm proposing that it has all the forces of regular matter and they interact with dark matter, but that they do not interact with regular matter - except for gravity of course.

Comment: Maybe [Worldbuilding SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for your question?

Comment: @Bosoneando, I think the question as it is worded would be better off here.  The question asks if, from a physics standpoint, if such a thing is plausible, not what a "dark parallel universe" would look like.

Comment: Looks like I'm talking about "mirror matter" that I found in Wikipedia. I'm suggesting that there could be a mirror matter that interacts with regular matter only  looks like I'm talking about "mirror matter" that I found in Wikipedia. I'm suggesting that there could be a mirror matter that inter-acts only via gravity.  Could it be detected,  even resolved in some detail, by gravitational lensing?

Comment: @Joshua I think that asking about dark matter selfinteractions is fine here, but going beyond and asking about even dark civilizations... well, it seems a little in the realm of fantasy for me.

Comment: I concur, asking about dark intelligent beings appears more scifi than fact. Querying about dark atoms/stars/planets/galaxies etc *should* be okay, but might be a duplicate of a question asked previously.

Comment: Well it is a bit of fantasy, but it would interject a bit of symmetry.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos could you cite the question asked previously?

Comment: @RobertBlandford: [This question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52877/) asks specifically if star-sized clumps of dark matter could exist. Inference to larger objects from these answers (as well as John's here) is straight-forward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we have a parallel earth made of dark matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61223/)

Comment: Hi Robert. While chasing down Kyle's suggestion that related questions may exist i've come across a virtually exact duplicate. And indeed Chris White's answer to that question is virtually the same as my answer to this one.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos A "clump" of matter could be assembled using gravity only. It would be inert  without other forces. So it would not be a dark "star" or dark "earth".

Comment: this is definitely not a duplicate, since in this question there is the possibility of 'dark dyson swarms' made of hadronic matter, but that are way colder than what one would expect from the usual heat waste analysis. Such 'dark objects' have been ruled out to make up **all** of dark matter, but they could still make up a non-negligible fraction of it

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you take the usual position that dark matter interacts only via the weak and gravitational forces, then it doesn't just interact weakly with baryonic matter but it also interacts weakly with other dark matter. That makes it extremely unlikely that dark matter will form the sort of complex structures that make up you and I. I'm afraid it seems very unlikely that dark matter will form anything more structured than a fuzzy blob.

There have been suggestions for types of dark matter that does interact strongly with itself, but not with baryonic matter. For example [mirror matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter). However such suggestions are entirely speculative without a shred of experimental evidence to back them up.